# Linux ip6_tables xt_percpu_counter_free (err 0)

Tags: linux, debian, iptables, ip6tables

Today I wanted install a new server instance with ansible and our existent playbooks. The base system is a Debian 9.4.

The firewall role failed, but I do not think that it is an ansible or role problem.

Perhaps there is just a small thing missing.

Introducing myself:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ... 4.9.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.82-1+deb9u3 (2018-03-02) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

First I checked the status of the firewall:

```
$ systemctl status firewall
● firewall.service - Firewall
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/firewall.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-05-16 15:59:55 CEST; 42min ago
  Process: 3758 ExecStart=/etc/firewall.bash (code=exited, status=3)
 Main PID: 3758 (code=exited, status=3)
      CPU: 43ms

May 16 15:59:55 ... firewall.bash[3758]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ip6_tables': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown 
May 16 15:59:55 ... firewall.bash[3758]: ip6tables v1.6.0: can't initialize ip6tables table `filter': Table does not exist (do
May 16 15:59:55 ... firewall.bash[3758]: Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
May 16 15:59:55 ... firewall.bash[3758]: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ip6_tables': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown 
May 16 15:59:55 ... firewall.bash[3758]: ip6tables v1.6.0: can't initialize ip6tables table `filter': Table does not exist (do
May 16 15:59:55 ... firewall.bash[3758]: Perhaps ip6tables or your kernel needs to be upgraded.
May 16 15:59:55 ... systemd[1]: firewall.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
May 16 15:59:55 ... systemd[1]: Failed to start Firewall.
May 16 15:59:55 ... systemd[1]: firewall.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 16 15:59:55 ... systemd[1]: firewall.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

After that, I looked up the loaded kernel modules:

```
$ lsmod | grep filter
br_netfilter           24576  0
bridge                135168  1 br_netfilter
iptable_filter         16384  1
ip_tables              24576  3 iptable_mangle,iptable_filter,iptable_nat
x_tables               36864  10 xt_comment,xt_LOG,iptable_mangle,ip_tables,iptable_filter,xt_tcpudp,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_limit,xt_addrtype,xt_conntrack
```

So, no ip6_tables module, as it is loaded on our other servers. Next I tried to load the module:

```
$ modprobe ip6_tables (or modprobe ip6table_filter)
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ip6_tables': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
```

And now the relevant dmesg output:

```
$ dmesg
...
[ 9606.265051] ip6_tables: Unknown symbol xt_percpu_counter_free (err 0)
[ 9606.265850] ip6_tables: Unknown symbol xt_percpu_counter_alloc (err 0)
...
```

Under /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/ I found both IPv6 modules.

```
./kernel/net/ipv6/netfilter/ip6_tables.ko
./kernel/net/ipv6/netfilter/ip6table_filter.ko
```

If you search for it (ip6_tables: Unknown symbol xt_percpu_counter_free (err 0)), you will not find much. A pastebin (https://pastebin.com/mu9HX2xq) with the output of the dmesg but no further information.

Any ideas?

Comment: the file `/lib/modules/4.9.0-6-amd64/modules.symbols` should contain `alias symbol:xt_percpu_counter_alloc x_tables` . does it? perhaps something like depmod -a .. would work?

Comment: Yes it has both entries which are logged via dmsg.

    `alias symbol:xt_percpu_counter_alloc x_tables`
    `alias symbol:xt_percpu_counter_free x_tables`

Comment: A `depmod -a` is not fixing the issue.

Comment: I just did a new debian install and upgraded to the latest packages. I am getting the same errors in dmesg with ip6tables, iptables works fine.

Comment: It turns out all I needed to do was reboot the system. See my answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/915485/ip6-tables-unknown-symbol-unable-to-initialize-table-filter

Comment: Yes, it turned out, that the automated update via ansible installed a newer ABI of the kernel modules, but the newer kernel it self was not started. Rebooted and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

So I went to: https://packages.debian.org/linux-image-4.9.0-6-amd64

I downloaded the latest file from this page:

https://packages.debian.org/stretch/linux-image-4.9.0-6-amd64

called:

linux-image-4.9.0-6-amd64_4.9.88-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb

And installed it:

dpkg -i linux-image-4.9.0-6-amd64_4.9.88-1+deb9u1_amd64.deb

Rebooted and it worked, the problem went away.

So I guess in a slightly newer version it was fixed.

Comment: I just encountered the same issue. Will installing an image manually like this will there be any issues with trying to upgrade the system later or is it better to wait until an apt-get upgrade becomes available?

Comment: It turns out all I needed to do was reboot the system. See my answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/915485/ip6-tables-unknown-symbol-unable-to-initialize-table-filter