# IP6_tables unknown symbol, unable to initialize table 'filter'

Tags: linux, iptables, debian-stretch

On Debian 9, when trying to use iptables to create a set of rules, it works for IPv4 but not IPv6. With IPv6 I get the following error:

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'ip6_tables': Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter (see dmesg)
ip6tables-restore v1.6.0: ip6tables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter'
```

When I look at dmesg I see the following two errors:

```
ip6_tables: Unknown symbol xt_percpu_counter_free (err 0)
ip6_tables: Unknown symbol xt_percpu_counter_alloc (err 0)
```

What exactly is this error telling me and why am I getting it?

On [this page](https://serverfault.com/questions/912525/linux-ip6-tables-xt-percpu-counter-free-err-0) the OP found a solution of manually installing a new Linux kernel. Is this a preferred solution? Will manually installing a new kernel like this cause problems in the future when I try to upgrade the system with apt-get?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I simply needed to reboot the server. It was a new system install and I did an `apt-get update` / `apt-get upgrade` on it to make sure everything was updated. During the upgrade it must have installed the updated kernel for me but I was unaware that I needed to reboot the system.

After rebooting the system everything is working fine.